# Appending specific words to other words on separate lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of scientific names (genera, species, infraspecific names) split on separate lines.

```
Synonyms are shown in italics
Solanaceae
Solenomelus Miers
biflorus (Thunb.) Baker
Spirodela Schleiden
punctata (C. A. Meyer) C.
Thompson
Suaeda Forskal ex Scop.
argentinensis Soriano
fruticosa auct., non Forskal
patagonica Speg.
var. crassiuscula Soriano
Symphyostemon Miers ex Lindley
biflorus (Thunb.) Dusén
...
```

I would like to append each species, infraspecific (if applicable) and author names with their respective genus on a single line.

Note that:
- genera start with a capital letter and are followed by an author name also starting with a capital letter or a `(`.
- species are in lowercase.
- infraspecific names start with either `var.` or `ssp.`.
- a single word that does not end with `eae` is an author name.

So far my code is as follows:

```
from regex import search
genus_re = r'^[A-Z][a-z]+\s*[(A-Z]'
species_re = r'^[a-z]+\s*(?:[(A-Z]|(?:auct|var|ssp)\.)'
infsp_re = r'^(?:var|ssp)\..+'
author_nl_re = r'^[A-Z][a-z]+(?<!eae)$'

species_ls = []
flag = 0
with open('species_index.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        find_genus = search(genus_re, line)
        if find_genus:
            tmp_genus = []
            genus = search(r'^[A-Z][^A-Z\s]+', line)[0]
            tmp_genus.append(genus)
        if search(species_re, line):
            sp = search('.+', line)[0]
            species_ls.append(tmp_genus[0] + ' ' + sp)
```

I manage to append species names to their respective genus but I feel like I am over complicating things and struggle to append isolated author and infraspecific names.

The expected output is:

```
Solenomelus biflorus (Thunb.) Baker
Spirodela punctata (C. A. Meyer) C. Thompson
Suaeda argentinensis Soriano
Suaeda fruticosa auct., non Forskal
Suaeda patagonica var. crassiuscula Soriano
Symphyostemon biflorus (Thunb.) Dusén
```

Comment: Genera are always followed by an author name. `Solanaceae` is a family name. Family names always end with `eae`. A single word in a line is either a family or an author name. So I can distinguish between those two with the ending of the word. If it doesn't end with `eae`, it means it's an author.

Comment: This is quite challenges because (as far as I can see), there it is difficult to distinguish between a line containing a single author, and another line containing only a genra. For instance, in your posted data: `Solanaceae` and `Thompson`. Is one (or multiple lines of) genra always followed by an author, and are *all* genra names ending with `aea`?

Comment: .. also, I believe you might have two typos in the code that you may want to correct: it's `from re import search`, not `regex`. And on the very last line, I think you mean `tmp_genus` and not `tmp_g`.

Comment: @magnus The name of the library is correct, `regex` and not `re`, which is a newer version of the `re` module if I'm not mistaken. It offers many advantages such as fuzzy matching directly in the regex pattern. Please see https://pypi.org/project/regex/. Thank for pointing out the typo, going to fix it.

Comment: I see, I did not know about `regex`, thanks for enlightening me. I'm using version 3.6.9, and its not standard there.

Comment: Can you please clarify how the line `"Solenomelus Miers"` followed be the line `"biflorus (Thunb.) Baker"` should end up as `"Solenomelus biflorus (Thunb.) Baker"`? I'm unable to interpret how/why the rules should discard `"Miers"`. I first assumed *Miers* was an author, but after googling, I'm not so sure anymore.

Comment: In taxonomy, we split living organisms in different levels (e.g. order, family, genus, species, subspecies/variety). Genus and lower levels always have authorship to avoid confusion in case of several names are identical. We usually only write the authorship of the lower level. The reason is because with a well identified low level, we can easily retrieve the correct higher levels. Technically, it's not an issue if I keep the authorship of each level in the final output. It's just for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my script to solve your problem. It's a bit messy but hopefully it helps.

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------
# ---Globals----------------------------------------------------
# --------------------------------------------------------------
processed_lines = []

# --------------------------------------------------------------
# ---Helper Classes---------------------------------------------
# --------------------------------------------------------------
class State:
    GENUS = 0
    SPECIES = 1
    INFSP = 2

class ProcessedLine:
    def __init__(self):
        self.genus = ""
        self.species = ""
        self.infsp = ""
        self.author = ""

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}{}{}{}".format(self.genus, self.species, self.infsp, self.author)

    def set_genus(self, value):
        self.genus = value

    def set_species(self, value):
        self.species += " " + value

    def set_infsp(self, value):
        self.infsp += " " + value

    def set_author(self, value):
        self.author += " " + value

# --------------------------------------------------------------
# ---Functions--------------------------------------------------
# --------------------------------------------------------------
def process_line(state, split_line):
    return_state = state
    if state == State.GENUS:
        return_state = process_genus(split_line)
    elif state == State.SPECIES:
        return_state = process_species(split_line)
    elif state == State.INFSP:
        return_state = process_infsp(split_line)
    else:
        print("Error: Invalid state")
    return return_state

def process_genus(split_line):
    if processed_lines[-1].genus != "":
        # Need to create new ProcessedLine
        processed_lines.append(ProcessedLine())

    if len(split_line) == 1:
        # Check if Author name
        if split_line[0][-3:] != "eae":
            # Part of Author, append to previous line author
            processed_lines[-2].set_author(split_line[0])
        # Still looking for Genus next
        return State.GENUS
    else:
        if split_line[0][0].isupper() == False:
            # This is another species, use Genus from previous
            processed_lines[-1].set_genus(processed_lines[-2].genus)
            return process_species(split_line)
        else:
            processed_lines[-1].genus = split_line[0]
            return State.SPECIES

def process_species(split_line):
    # Check if words are species or author
    for word in split_line:
        if word[0].islower():
            processed_lines[-1].set_species(word)
        else:
            processed_lines[-1].set_author(word)
    return State.INFSP

def process_infsp(split_line):
    if split_line[0] == "var." or split_line[0] == "ssp.":
        # Author value needs to be replaced so we'll clear it
        processed_lines[-1].author = ""

        # Check if words are infraspecific or author
        for word in split_line:
            if word[0].islower():
                processed_lines[-1].set_infsp(word)
            else:
                processed_lines[-1].set_author(word)
        return State.GENUS
    else:
        # No infraspecific names, let process_genus handle this
        return process_genus(split_line)

# --------------------------------------------------------------
# ---Main-------------------------------------------------------
# --------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    state = State.GENUS
    processed_lines.append(ProcessedLine())
    with open('species_index.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

        for line in lines:
            line = line.rstrip()
            state = process_line(state, line.split(" "))

    print("Finished! Checking results.")
    for line in processed_lines:
        print(line)
```

Input:

```
Solanaceae
Solenomelus Miers
biflorus (Thunb.) Baker
Spirodela Schleiden
punctata (C. A. Meyer) C.
Thompson
Suaeda Forskal ex Scop.
argentinensis Soriano
fruticosa auct., non Forskal
patagonica Speg.
var. crassiuscula Soriano
Symphyostemon Miers ex Lindley
biflorus (Thunb.) Dusén
```

Output

```
Finished! Checking results.
Solenomelus biflorus (Thunb.) Baker
Spirodela punctata (C. A. Meyer) C. Thompson
Suaeda argentinensis Soriano
Suaeda fruticosa auct., non Forskal
Suaeda patagonica var. crassiuscula Soriano
Symphyostemon biflorus (Thunb.) DusÃ©n
```